# Detect if MPI compiler is used in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, preprocessor

I would like to write a Fortran code that could use MPI if it is compiled by `mpif90` but that could also run if it is compiled with `gfortran` (only, without MPI lib).
So I though using a preprocessing condition, but looking on the Internet I found nothing about such preprocessing variable defined by MPI.

For example, I would like to compile this trivial code `test.f90`:

```
Program Main
#ifdef __MPI
    USE MPI
#endif
    implicite none
    integer Ierror

#ifdef __MPI
    call MPI_INTI(Ierror)
    write (*,*) 'MPI detected'
#else
    write (*,*) 'MPI not detected'
#endif

End
```

Then, if I compile the previous Non-working example with `mpif90` I shoud get

```
$ mpif90 -cpp -o prog test.f90 && prog
> MPI detected
```

while if I compile with `gfortran`, I should get

```
$ gfortran -cpp -o prog test.f90 && prog
> MPI not detected
```

So is there a preprocessing condition (or another way) that could make this kind of example working ?

Comment: Are you asking `mpif90` to automatically insert `-D __MPI` for you? As in `mpif90 -cpp -D __MPI -o prog test.f90`?

Comment: You might have to rename into `test.F90` so it gets preprocessed.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353969/does-mpi-provide-preprocessor-macros but read the comments carefully - essentially the conclusion is no, this is not possible.

Comment: @IanBush thanks for the link. However, I think that the solution of MattShin could be viable solution, or am I mistaking ?

Comment: I'm reading your question as asking if the mpif90 compiler does this or similar automatically. The linked question says no. But if you are willing to manually add yourself -D __MPI or similar and go through the horror for program maintenance that is preprocessing, then yes you can do it that way. Personally I think all code should be parallel nowadays, so I would just have the MPI version.

Comment: @IanBush okay. thanks for this opinion, I will think about it and reconsider my position !

Comment: @MattShin That is exactly the approach I am taking. For example in https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/SConstruct